# Where did the animated section of this image come from?

Tags: dc, batman, episode-identification

The bottom still is from Suicide Squad, but what episode of what animated incarnation of Batman is the top still in this meme taken from?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's from [*The New Batman Adventures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Batman_Adventures), a continuation of [*Batman: The Animated Series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Animated_Series) with a modified art style to fit with the other DCAU shows, and also to make the show cheaper to animate.

The particular episode is "Mad Love", which tells Harley Quinn's origin story. It's an adaptation of a [1994 comic book of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Batman_Adventures:_Mad_Love), written by Paul Dini.

You can see a similar image on the [ComicVine page for the episode](http://www.comicvine.com/the-new-batman-adventures-121-mad-love/4070-4474/):

[image]

Comment: "Modern art style" = cheap lazy garbage

Comment: @Broklynite "cheap" and "lazy" being two of the motivating factors for the change (not a joke)

Comment: I know, I know. Still hate it tho

Comment: What got me is that they still drew so many other people the same -- and drew Bruce Wayne with *more* detail! Remember, he used to look identical to Superman.